# Why OpenMP under ubuntu 12.04 is slower than serial version

Tags: c++, ubuntu, pthreads, openmp

I've read some other questions on this topic.
However, they didn't solve my problem anyway.

I wrote the code as following and I got `pthread` version and `omp` version both slower than the serial version. I'm very confused.

Compiled under environment:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 64bit 3.2.0-60-generic
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1

CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            18
Model:                 1
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              3593.36
L1d cache:             64K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              512K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
```

Compile command:

`g++ -std=c++11 ./eg001.cpp -fopenmp`

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <omp.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 5
const int sizen = 256000000;

struct Data {
    double * pSinTable;
    long tid;
};

void * compute(void * p) {
    Data * pDt = (Data *)p;
    const int start = sizen * pDt->tid/NUM_THREADS;
    const int end = sizen * (pDt->tid + 1)/NUM_THREADS;
    for(int n = start; n < end; ++n) {
        pDt->pSinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / sizen);
    }
    pthread_exit(nullptr);
}

int main()
{
    double * sinTable = new double[sizen];
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    clock_t start, finish;

    start = clock();
    int rc;
    Data dt[NUM_THREADS];
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        dt[i].pSinTable = sinTable;
        dt[i].tid = i;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, compute, &dt[i]);
    }//for
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        rc = pthread_join(threads[i], nullptr);
    }//for
    finish = clock();
    printf("from pthread: %lf\n", (double)(finish - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    delete sinTable;
    sinTable = new double[sizen];

    start = clock();
#   pragma omp parallel for
    for(int n = 0; n < sizen; ++n)
        sinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / sizen);
    finish = clock();
    printf("from omp: %lf\n", (double)(finish - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    delete sinTable;
    sinTable = new double[sizen];

    start = clock();
    for(int n = 0; n < sizen; ++n)
        sinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / sizen);
    finish = clock();
    printf("from serial: %lf\n", (double)(finish - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    delete sinTable;

    pthread_exit(nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
from pthread: 21.150000
from omp: 20.940000
from serial: 20.800000
```

I wonder whether it was my code's problem so I used pthread to do the same thing.

However, I'm totally wrong, and I wonder whether it might be Ubuntu's problem on OpenMP/pthread.

I have a friend who has AMD CPU and Ubuntu 12.04 as well, and got the same problem there, so I might have some reason to believe that the problem is not limited to only me.

If anyone has the same problem as me, or has some clue on the problem, thanks in advance.

---

If the code is not good enough, I ran a benchmark and I pasted the result here:

http://pastebin.com/RquLPREc

The benchmark url: http://www.cs.kent.edu/~farrell/mc08/lectures/progs/openmp/microBenchmarks/src/download.html

---

New infomation:

I ran the code on windows (without pthread version) with VS2012.

I used 1/10 of sizen because windows does not allow me to allocate that great trunk of memory where the results are:

```
from omp: 1.004
from serial: 1.420
from FreeNickName: 735 (this one is the suggestion improvement by @FreeNickName)
```

Does this indicate that it could be a problem of `Ubuntu OS` ??

---

---

Problem is solved by using `omp_get_wtime` function that is portable among Operating Systems. See the answer by `Hristo Iliev`.

---

Some tests about the controversial topic by `FreeNickName`.

(Sorry I need to test it on Ubuntu cause the windows was one of my friends'.)

--1-- Change from `delete` to `delete []` : (but without memset)(-std=c++11 -fopenmp)

```
from pthread: 13.491405
from omp: 13.023099
from serial: 20.665132
from FreeNickName: 12.022501
```

--2-- With memset immediately after new: (-std=c++11 -fopenmp)

```
from pthread: 13.996505
from omp: 13.192444
from serial: 19.882127
from FreeNickName: 12.541723
```

--3-- With memset immediately after new: (-std=c++11 -fopenmp -march=native -O2)

```
from pthread: 11.886978
from omp: 11.351801
from serial: 17.002865
from FreeNickName: 11.198779
```

--4-- With memset immediately after new, and put FreeNickName's version before OMP for version: (-std=c++11 -fopenmp -march=native -O2)

```
from pthread: 11.831127
from FreeNickName: 11.571595
from omp: 11.932814
from serial: 16.976979
```

--5-- With memset immediately after new, and put FreeNickName's version before OMP for version, and set `NUM_THREADS` to 5 instead of 2 (I'm dual core).

```
from pthread: 9.451775
from FreeNickName: 9.385366
from omp: 11.854656
from serial: 16.960101
```

Comment: Is it only slower in Ubuntu? Concurrency does not always yield in performance improvement, if your workload is not grained appropriately you will likely experience a performance drop.

Comment: @ddriver My friend has a CentOS as well, which parallel version is faster.

Comment: Try with 2 threads only, that's as much as your CPU actually has. No need to run 5 threads on a system that has only two. The threads might very well be fighting for resources, which would explain the drop

Comment: @ddriver it didn't help. Serial version is stil the fastest. `from pthread: 20.960000`, `from omp: 21.010000`, `from serial: 20.840000`

Comment: Then I don't know what is wrong... your workloads seems to be high enough, 20 seconds running time is more than plenty to eliminate the margin of error. You create the threads in advance so it is not that either.  Hopefully someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: Did you try looking at a CPU usage level while your program is running? Does it use all cores, or just one?

Comment: @FreeNickname Yes, I did with the help of `time` command and system was greater than 100% indicating more than one core is used.

Comment: @FreeNickname, I added windows running results in the post. You may be interested to take a look.

Comment: -1 measure wall-clock time, not CPU time!

Comment: I hope that this is just an example, and not your real program. In most cases, it will be far faster to recompute the sine than to use a table look up. Your FPU is probably faster than your main memory.

Comment: @pburka yep, it's just an example.

Comment: When you were measuring the FreeNickName's version on Windows, did you run two separate programs, one with simple OpenMP `parallel for` and one with FreeNIckName's modification or did you have the three versions in a single executable file in the same order as shown in your question, namely OpenMP, then serial, then FreeNickName?

Comment: @HristoIliev One single executable file. Is there anything out of my consideration?

Comment: Move the codes around, e.g. put FreeNickName's version first and run the test, then put the serial version first and run the test.

Comment: Or just put a `memset(sinTable, 0, sizen*sizeof(double));` immediately after the first `new` (that would be the second line of the `main` function). Otherwise you are giving an unfair advantage to the second and the third version.

Comment: @Adam, note: run it on Windows as you did before, please. I'm curious too :) If you're wondering, why we are we asking you to do it, see comments to my answer, there is a small discussion down there.

Comment: @HristoIliev, then we should put a `memset` after each `new`, shouldn't we? There is no guarantee, that we will get the same memory space on the second `new` and the third view? Or is there something that I missed? By the way, @Adam, you should use `delete [] sinTable;` instead of `delete sinTable;` since you're deleting an array.

Comment: The results from the EPCC OpenMP microbenchmarks have a very broad distribution. That's either due to dynamic power and frequency management of the CPU (TurboBoost or whatever AMD call their variant) or the scheduler moving the threads around. Do an `export GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-n"` (where `n` is the #logical_CPUs minus 1) before running the microbenchmarks.

Comment: @FreeNickname and Hristo lliev, and pburka, I updated the performance tests on different occasions. I think you guys will be interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with OpenMP in your case. What is wrong is the way you measure the elapsed time.

Using `clock()` to measure the performance of multithreaded applications on Linux (and most other Unix-like OSes) is a mistake since it does not return the wall-clock (real) time but instead the accumulated CPU time for all process threads (and on some Unix flavours even the accumulated CPU time for all child processes). Your parallel code shows better performance on Windows since there `clock()` returns the real time and not the accumulated CPU time.

The best way to prevent such discrepancies is to use the portable OpenMP timer routine `omp_get_wtime()`:

```
double start = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int n = 0; n < sizen; ++n)
    sinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / sizen);
double finish = omp_get_wtime();
printf("from omp: %lf\n", finish - start);
```

For non-OpenMP applications, you should use `clock_gettime()` with the `CLOCK_REALTIME` clock:

```
struct timespec start, finish;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int n = 0; n < sizen; ++n)
    sinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / sizen);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &finish);
printf("from omp: %lf\n", (finish.tv_sec + 1.e-9 * finish.tv_nsec) -
                          (start.tv_sec + 1.e-9 * start.tv_nsec));
```

Comment: I wonder whether `clock()` function is a C-standard function, and if so, how could it be non-portable??

Comment: [clock()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock.html) is an ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (a.k.a. C90) and SUSv3 standard function indeed, but its poor definition and the pre-existing discrepancies prompted the development of the new portable `clock_gettime()` interface.

Comment: Well, I googled `clock_gettime()`, and I found out that it's just portable among *nix, but not windows (That's quite sad).

Comment: That's why you should use `omp_get_wtime()` as it is portable among all platforms that support OpenMP and it always returns real time.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux scheduler, in the absence of any information, will tend to schedule threads in a process on the same core so that they are served by the same cache and memory bus. It has no way of knowing that your threads will be accessing different memory so won't be hurt instead of helped by being on different cores.

Use the sched_setaffinity function to set each thread to a different core mask.

Comment: I used `time` command to calculate the cpu usage (I ran only pthread version) and it gave me: `from pthread: 20.760000 ./a.out  19.67s user 1.29s system 164% cpu 12.741 total`

Comment: If `sched_setaffinity` is needed on your platform, then surely the omp runtime platform support code will invoke it for you.

Comment: How about setting the `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` environment variable instead of messing with non-portable system calls?

Answer (score -2):

**WARNING: tho answer is controversial. The trick described below is implementation dependent and can lead to a decrease of performance.**
Still, it might increase it as well. I strongly recommend to take a look at comments to this answer.

---

This doesn't really answer the question, but if you alter the way you parallelize your code, you might get a performance boost. Now you do it like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int n = 0; n < sizen; ++n)
    sinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / sizen);
```

In this case each thread will compute one item. Since you have 2 cores, OpenMP will create two threads by default. To calculate each value a thread would have to:

1. Initialize.
2. Compute values.

The first step is rather expensive. And both your threads would have to do it `sizen/2` times.
Try to do the following:

```
    int workloadPerThread = sizen / NUM_THREADS;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int thread = 0; thread < NUM_THREADS; ++thread)
    {
        int start = thread * workloadPerThread;
        int stop = start + workloadPerThread;
        if (thread == NUM_THREADS - 1)
                stop += sizen % NUM_THREADS;
        for (int n = start; n < stop; ++n)
            sinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / sizen);
    }
```

This way your threads will initialize only once.

Comment: I suggest that you might have taken the wrong path on the question where the benchmark result would like to explain that any improvement on code will not humbly affect the result. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion nevertheless it didn't work: `from pthread: 20.730000; from omp: 20.800000; from serial: 20.780000; from FreeNickname: 20.850000`

Comment: Yes, sorry. If it was a pure OpenMP problem, ptheads would run faster than the serial version. Still, my answer might help you to improve `omp` performance, when you will deal with this strange behaviour you get, so, I guess, I'll leave it here.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The compiler / runtime will divide the work up for you. Dividing it up by hand as you've demonstrated will be unlikely to show any improvement, and makes the code much more difficult to read.

Comment: @pburka, and now read the question again, please. Up to the end.

Comment: I tend to agree with @pburka. Your code is an unnecessary overcomplication of what `parallel for schedule(static)` does anyway. And though not explicitly specified in the original question, `schedule(static)` is the implementation-specific default for virtually any existing OpenMP compiler when no `schedule` clause is specified.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I guess, it is implementation defined. Still, I encountered situations in my practice, when a simple `parallel for` worked close to (or worse than) a serial version, because chunks of work were too small, whereas a 'manual parallization' gave a speedup close to linear in respect to the number of cores. May be I worked with a bad OpenMP implementation in my hands, but the fact is that at least some versions of OpenMP hate small chunks of work. Thus, my answer.

Comment: Which OpenMP implementation was that? Most compilers default to static scheduling since it's the easiest one to implement in code.

Comment: @HristoIliev, It's hard to tell, unfortunately. It might've been a GCC 4.5, but I'm not sure. The code looked for prime numbers. Dividing candidates into large chunks worked much faster, than a simple `parallel for`. Still, I tested my version now on OS X 10.9 with GCC 4.8.2, and it's considerably slower, than the original. But, as the OP mentioned in the end, my version is faster on Windows with VS 2012. I will add a warning to my answer, but I'll keep it, since it might help someone.

Comment: I strongly suspect that your version is faster on Windows because it uses already pre-faulted memory (if the OP has indeed the three code versions in a single executable, then the OpenMP version is at disadvantage of having to fault the memory). On OS X pre-faulting the 1,9 GiB array saves 3 seconds out of 8 for the OpenMP version.