# Why OpenMP with random number generation is slower than serial code

Tags: c++, random, openmp

I'm trying use OpenMP to add parallelism to my program.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 generator(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(-0.5, 0.5);

#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    float x = distribution(generator);
}
```

I tested the code on windows (Visual Studio 2010) and linux (Centos 6.5, gcc 4.9.1) on 12 core processors, and found the parallel version was slower than the serial code.

The results as below:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -Ofast
time ./test
real    0m1.234s
user    0m1.229s
sys 0m0.004s

g++ test.cpp -o test -fopenmp -std=c++11 -Ofast
time ./test
real    0m1.708s
user    0m24.218s
sys 0m0.010s
```

Why is the the OpenMP is slower than the serial code?

Comment: Probably because random is gotten from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`. `random` is blocking, `urandom` is not blocking. So if it was blocking, then the parallel version would likely be slower. Just a guess.

Comment: Using a shared PRNG object accross different threads is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: If you want to make the program faster, do not forget to turn optimization on by adding the `-O3` option to the compiler.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184527/why-openmp-under-ubuntu-12-04-is-slower-than-serial-version/23190865#23190865). I got downvoted there, but as you can see from the comments to the original post, I was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using one random number generator across many threads. Each call for a new random number will block all the other parallel calls until it is finished.

If you would profile the code, chances are all (or most) of the execution time is spent in some form of mutex locking/unlocking. This problem is called [contention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29#Granularity) and your scenario would be a schoolbook example of how to cause it.

If you use `std::thread`s and give each thread a separate rng, you will achieve pretty much 100% parallelization for that part of the code.

Some code to get you started using `std::thread` below. Note the use of `std::ref`

```
#include <array>
  using std::array;
#include <cstddef>
  using std::size_t;
#include <functional>
  using std::ref;
#include <iostream>
  using std::cout;
#include <iterator>
  using std::iterator_traits;
#include <thread>
  using std::thread;
#include <vector>
  using std::vector;
#include <random>
  using mersenne_twister = std::mt19937;

template<class T, T N>
array<T, N> series_of_numbers()
{
  array<T, N> arr;
  for(T i=0; i<N; ++i)
    arr[i] = i;

  return arr;
}

template<class Iterator, class Engine>
void generate_rng(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Engine& engine)
{
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist;
  for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    *it = dist(engine);
}

int main()
{
  const size_t amount_of_random_numbers = 1024;
  // Engines
  const size_t Nrng = 4;
  auto seed_values = series_of_numbers<size_t, Nrng>(); // choose other seeds if you wish
  array<mersenne_twister, Nrng> engines;
  for(size_t i=0; i<Nrng; ++i)
    engines[i].seed(seed_values[i]);

  vector<thread> threads;
  vector<double> rngs(amount_of_random_numbers);

  // relevant iterators with offsets
  vector<vector<double>::iterator> begins = { rngs.begin(),
                                              rngs.begin() + amount_of_random_numbers/Nrng,
                                              rngs.begin() + 2*amount_of_random_numbers/Nrng,
                                              rngs.begin() + 3*amount_of_random_numbers/Nrng };

  vector<vector<double>::iterator> ends = { rngs.end(),
                                              rngs.end() - 3*amount_of_random_numbers/Nrng,
                                              rngs.end() - 2*amount_of_random_numbers/Nrng,
                                              rngs.end() - amount_of_random_numbers/Nrng };
  // create threads
  for(size_t n=0; n<Nrng; ++n)
    threads.emplace_back(thread(generate_rng<decltype(begins[n]), mersenne_twister>, ref(begins[n]), ref(ends[n]), ref(engines[n])));

  // join threads -> this is where the work will be done.
  for(size_t n=0; n<Nrng; ++n)
    threads[n].join();

  // rngs is filled with magical values!
  for(auto number : rngs)
    std::cout << number << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/905be43ce3e1706b). And [another version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa2f2122220fe110) where you can actually change the number of threads to any multiple of 4

Comment: Why not just skip the paragraph that goes "Some code I used quite a while ago to achieve parallel random number generation:" and add it with the relevant edit? If you skipped it in the first iteration and had a fatal stroke while producing the code, the answer would not look unfinished.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I thought it would be faster to copy paste, apparently it's not. Sorry for the unfinished answer...

Comment: @dolan the one introduced by OpenMP to guard access to an object which is shared across threads.

Comment: I'm sorry for giving the impression that if you had a fatal stroke I'd be more worried about the answer looking unfinished. ;)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I'm sure robots don't care much for people stroking out as much as they care about this site's database ;-)

Comment: Are you sure the MT implementation uses locks to protect the generation of PRNs? I would rather say it doesn't and what the OP exhibits is the cache trashing effect of data races over the shared PRNG state vector. Also, OpenMP **does not guard access to shared objects with mutexes** - where did you pick up that misconception? The solution to use multiple PRNGs is correct though.