# scalability of MPI on one machine

Tags: mpi, scalability

I encounter a problem about the scalability of MPI solver on one machine. I want to do twenty matrix summations. This work is done in two way:
1. 20 tasks are launched by MPI, each task do one matrix summations for one round.
2. 2 tasks are launched by MPI, each task do one matrix summation per round and do ten rounds of calculation. Different task are synchronized between different rounds.
CPU time of matrix summation per each round is recorded for both two ways. CPU time does NOT include memory allocation and release, also does NOT include the matrix creation. 
As I expect, the CPU time per round in two ways should be the same since each task only calculate one matrix summation in each round and there is no communication between tasks, e.g. calculation of each task are independent. That means the scalability of this solver should be perfect.

But CPU time of the first way (20 MPI tasks) is more than ten times of CPU time of the second way (2 MPI tasks). What is the possible reason of it? Is it related to cache in the memory?

Comment: Sizes of matrices? If like under 64x64, thread switch overhead probably  be larger.

Comment: 10000x10000 but it is a sparse matrix with around 100000 nonzero elements. what is thread switch?  I thought different tasks are independent completely so there is no need for thread switch?

Comment: How many cores does your one machine have ?  And how are you measuring the *CPU time* ?  What timing routine(s) are you using ?

Comment: 16 cores with 32 threads, I measure the CPU time by clock();

Comment: Even I try 10 tasks with 2 round. The CPU time is still more than 4 times of CPU time with 2 tasks.

Comment: Actually, this answer --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184527/why-openmp-under-ubuntu-12-04-is-slower-than-serial-version -- is probably a better reference for you.

Comment: In the answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184527/why-openmp-under-ubuntu-12-04-is-slower-than-serial-version, clock() do report real time in windows. This simulation is on windows machine, should I use other time function?